# s3 chunked uploads with blueimp.fileupload

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, blueimp

I'm implementing AWS chunked uploads using the blueimp plugin, and I've run into a problem in the event ordering.

Instead of `Content-Range` (presence of which causes Amazon to immediately throw a 403), S3 uses an upload ID and part number query parameters.

So before each chunk, I need to reach out to my signing service and change the url of the next chunk.

It doesn't appear that options.chunksend blocks the event system like options.add, so my next chunk is sent to the same URL as the first chunk (set in options.add), overwriting it.

How can I block the send of a chunk so I can change the url?

Answer (score 1):

The chunksend event and the call to upload the chunk are simultaneous. I overrode this section of https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js:

```
            that._initProgressListener(o);
            jqXHR = ((that._trigger('chunksend', null, o) !== false && $.ajax(o)) ||
                    that._getXHRPromise(false, o.context))
                .done(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

to

```
            that._initProgressListener(o);
              o.uploadPromise = $.Deferred();
              that._trigger('chunksend', null, o);
              o.uploadPromise.done(function() {
                  jqXHR = ((that._trigger('stillneeded', null, o) !== false && $.ajax(o)) ||
                          that._getXHRPromise(false, o.context))
                      .done(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

And then resolve the promise in my chunksend event handler.

Comment: Hello Mark. Did you successfully get chunking to work with blueimp jquery file upload and s3? I am trying to do that right now and I am having a hard time figuring out what i need to do.

Comment: The solution in the down-voted answer above is what I use, and I have no problems at all.

The Blueimp uploader uses the Content-Range header, which blows up s3.  Instead, you remove the header and change the URL when each chunk sends.  I simply injected a promise to delay the execution of the next chunk until after the URL has been updated.

Comment: how do you account for the last 0 byte chunk? According to the documentation, this is necessary, and blueimp doesnt do that.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-streaming.html

Would you be willing to share your callback code within the $('fileupload').fileUpload() call?

Comment: I don't use that authentication method, I use the server-side client (boto in my case) to start the multipart uploads, each chunk uses a signed querystring, then the server side client calls complete multipart upload.  No zero-length chunk required.